# How to trigger a URL using php?

Tags: php

I want to trigger a URL without user interaction. I used

```
file_get_contents($myurl);
```

But in my webhost `file_get_contents()` is disabled. how to do that. I dont want to read the contents of the URL. I just want to trigger the URL. Also I can not use `header()` function, because, Im going to trigger the url in a loop, so header will not be helpful.

Comment: Often a simple email asking for something to be enabled/installed is enough to get your web host to do it.  But if not, maybe it's time to switch hosts :)

Answer (score 3):

Use [cURL](http://us.php.net/curl):

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.example.com'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
curl_exec(); 
curl_close($ch); 
?>
```

Comment: For this I have to include or install anything??

Comment: Yes, it's PHP extention and it must be installed and enabled

Comment: You'll need to have cURL installed (see http://us.php.net/manual/en/curl.requirements.php).

Comment: Judging by his PHP Info, he doesnt have CURL installed.

Comment: See my answer. Internally it should be exactly the same (retrieve the headers, but not the body). The good thing is, you don't need to have any library installed as is the case with Curl, since get_headers is built-in.

Comment: Ah, I need to take that back. `allow_url_fopen` is Off, no php solution will work. @Gordon's workaround is your only option.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you cannot use `Curl` or `fsockopen` or `exec wget` or any of the other suggestions to make it work from PHP, it is a lost cause. Almost. If you dont have to have the URL called during script execution, you could let the client call the url by adding an [WebBug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_bug) element to the html you send back to browser (assuming this is what you do), e.g.

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/trigger.php?arg1=foo" width="1" height="1"/>
```

If you need the response from the script, you could use an `iframe`, though you should check if that element is part of the Doctype you are using. You could also try via JavaScript, but have to find a way to bypass the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) most browsers enforce.

If that's still not solving your problem, try another [free hosting service](http://www.google.com/search?q=free+php+hosting) or consider switching to paid hosting. You can get a decent setup for below ten bucks nowadays.

Comment: Since `allow_url_fopen` is Off, this is the last resort indeed. Good catch.

Answer (score 2):

You could try some lower level socket calls to make a simple HTTP request with [fsockopen](http://php.net/fsockopen) and related functions. Here's a sample from the manual

```
$fp = fsockopen("www.example.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
   echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
   $out = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
   $out .= "Host: www.example.com\r\n";
   $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";

   fwrite($fp, $out);
   while (!feof($fp)) {
       echo fgets($fp, 128);
   }
   fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: fsockopen() also disabled by my webhost

Comment: Well, I would take that as a sign that maybe your host just doesn't want you do this. Find another host!

Comment: Any free php hosting site u know??

Comment: You're likely not going to get what you want for free.  Quality service costs money.  Pay for a decent webhost.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are the right way to go to actually "trigger" the other URLs.  But it is worth mentioning that if you're trying to request those URLs "without user interaction" you should consider running a [Cron Job](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to actually make it happen, rather than relying on someone to access a specific page on your website.

Comment: I want to trigger the URL based on Condition, Not on time interval

Answer (score 1):

If none of the other options work for you, you might be able to do it using the shell. Using `wget`:

```
shell_exec('wget http://example.com/');
```

If `wget` isn't installed, you might be able to do it with `lynx`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

Answer (score 0):

**update: ah, I see `allow_url_fopen` is off. Yeah, then even `get_headers` won't work. Then the solution from @Gordon is the way too go. A bit nasty, but there is no other option.

I would recommend to avoid such hosters like the plague, this is too limiting.**

---

In your last question I answered [`get_headers($url)`](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php). Thats all. 
This is definitively the way I would do it. It returns the headers, so that you are able to see if your request was handled properly.

Curl is also an option but I doubt if this is installed on your shared hosting, which seems to be restrictive.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample command to call another script from current file as a separate process

```
exec('/usr/bin/php5 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/PROCESS/processScript.php');
```